# Xamarin Forms and TLS 1.2

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, tls1.2

When Apple started to require TLS 1.2 I had issues with it and turned it off in the info.plist. Now that they are going to require that it not be turned off for apps in the app store, I'm revisiting it. I've found some Xamarin articles on it, such ashttps://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/transport-layer-security/ andhttps://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/#ATS-Connection-Requirements but they are not dated and the information does not appear to match my testing. What I have found it, running against a TLS 1.2 secured server, everything just works - both webviews and API calls using System.Net.Http.HttpClient (HttpClientHandler) return what is expected without error, without any special configuration. Are the articles above outdated?
I am also getting unexpected results when running against a non-secured server. The webviews do return an error as expected, but the API calls return JSON objects with the expected data, no security error. Why isn't TLS 1.2 required for these connections?
Any help / clarification would be much appreciated!

Comment: The default HttpClient does not use Apple's HTTP stack. Instead it uses a low level implementation from Mono. This implementation side-steps Apple's ATS requirements, which is why your API calls with HttpClient will work regardless of ATS settings. There is a new setting which can change that: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/http-stack/

Comment: Changing the HttpClient implementation does not change the behavior when testing on an iPhone running version 9.3.5.  Setting it to CFNetwork causes an exception when the app loading completes, NSUrlSession does not cause errors, but both return JSON when running against an unsecured server.

Comment: It's the `SSL/TLS` setting you'd want to change. It can be either Apple or Mono.

Comment: Does changing the 'HttpClient Implementation' change the HttpClient or the HttpClientHandler?

Comment: I ask because I'm using cookies, so I have to create the HttpClientHandler and use that to create the HttpClient
           
var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookieContainer };
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);

and when I do this the 'HttpClient implementation' does not appear to change anything.  But if instead I create the HttpClient without defining the handler

var httpClient = new HttpClient();

then using the NSUrlSession does return a security error.

Comment: It changes the `HttpClientHandler` implementation. The document I linked goes into more detail regarding each option.